# Aurelia - Asp.net Core SPA project has error on navmenu only - uncrementCounter is not a function

Tags: aurelia

I have Aurelia - ASP.NET core 2 template project.. You can download it from [GITHUB](https://github.com/si2030/Aurelia-aspnet-core-project.) and run it to verify the error.

I had made significant changes until I found an error in the navmenu.html not recognising a function.

I went back to the template and did a quick test and found the same error in the base template.

I registered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139725/aurelia-error-with-click-delegate-saying-the-function-is-not-a-function) question on my original solution with the same problem but have now realised its to do with the actual Aurelia template I got. So I have uploaded the entire project to github so someone can see the whole thing.

To get this error all I am doing is creating a function on the navmenu and referencing that on a button using "click.deligate".  Here is the navmenu.html:

```
<template bindable="router">
<require from="./navmenu.css"></require>
<div class="main-nav">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">Jobsledger.API</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li repeat.for = "row of router.navigation" class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }" >
                    <a href.bind = "row.href">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-${ row.settings.icon }"></span> ${ row.title }
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Counter</h1>

    <p>This is a simple example of an Aurelia component.</p>

    <p>Current count: <strong>${currentCount}</strong></p>

    <button click.delegate="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Here is the viewmodel.ts file

```
    import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

    @autoinject
    export class Navmenu {
        //loggedInService: LoggedInService;
        public currentCount = 0;

        public incrementCounter() {
            this.currentCount++;
        }
    }
```

The error is:

```
aurelia-binding.js:1905 Uncaught Error: incrementCounter is not a function
at getFunction (aurelia-binding.js:1905)
at CallScope.evaluate (aurelia-binding.js:1508)
at Listener.callSource (aurelia-binding.js:5082)
at Listener.handleEvent (aurelia-binding.js:5091)
at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent (aurelia-binding.js:3223)
```

As I say there is a working asp.net core solution that has the spa in it and can be downloaded from github.

It would be great if someone could assist me here as this is currently a show stopper for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring your **navmenu** as a template only, e.g. `<require from="../navmenu/navmenu.html"></require>`. In order to use your view with your javascript please see this [guide](http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements#bindable-properties) about custom elements.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Still not sure how to fix this in my situation. I have read the guide you suggested but I am not sure how to wire this up so that my viewmodel is accessed. Could you expand your answer?

Comment: Think I have cracked this thank god. Happy for anyone to eleborate..  Ok so janmvtrinidad was on the money here I think. I first of all changed the way navmenu is required in the parent in this case app.html. I took off the ".html" eg "<require from="../navmenu/navmenu"></require>".  I added @bindable to the variable currentCount and for the function I added callback.call="incrementCounter()" eg "<navmenu router.bind="router" callback.call="incrementCounter()"></navmenu>"